# route with parameters in yml Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'd like to add parameters on my routes that I use in yml, for example in security.yml

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: project_main_homepage
            default_target_path: project_user_profile
            failure_path: project_main_homepage
```

If I failed the login I will be redirect to project_main_homepage (http://www.mywebsite.com)
but for example I'd like to be redirected to http://www.mywebsite.com?user=0
is there a solution to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to add a URL get parameter directly in the security.yml file but this is totally possible by creating an authentication handler where you create your own RedirectResponse to a route (with parameters) of your choosing.  Check this article on creating an [authentication handler in symfony](http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/).

Another alternative is to create a second route that has a URL parameter to redirect to the same action, not sure if that would suit your needs since it would be a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add your parameters in /app/config/parameters.yml and to use them in routing.yml and in security.yml surrounded by %?

For example:

```
app/config/parameters.yml  
your_param: xxx

app/config/routing.yml
your_route:  
    pattern:  /%your_param%/{_locale}  
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Main:index }
```